# C one function with static variables parallel

Tags: c++

i would like to ask if there is a way to make a function with static int work paralleic, like, i would have:

```cpp
void func(){
    static int x=0;
    cout << x++;
}

int main(){

    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        func();
        if(i>5)
            func();
        if(i>8)
            func();
    }
}
```

Output of this program would be something like:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14
```

However it looks like: do func() when i<6, do func() func() when i<9 and do func() func() func() when i = 9 (i hope you get what im saying) so please dont blame me that I don't know how functions works.

There my question is, is there any way so I could get with similar program an output of:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 0 6 1 7 2 8 3 9 4 0
```

(not sure if I have shown it well, but I hope you get what im saying, so that the second call of func() would have new static int)

I've been thinking about giving some parameter to a function, but have no idea how to do it.

For now i have similiar function which takes input and 2 static ints:

```
void func(bool x){
static int t1=0;
static int t2=0;
if(x)
cout << t1++;
else
cout << t2++;
}

int main()
{
for(int i=0; i<10;i++)
{
func(0);
if(i>6)
func(1);
}
```

But i was looking for some more universal, because my actual code is much longer

Comment: Once the iniitalization of `x` is done (it's thread safe) the function is not reentrant. If it's called from multiple threads you will have a data race.

Comment: I was thinking about function delay(x, ticks);, that would print x after number of ticks, is there a way to do it? I mean, i would like to have this function, but it would be nice if it would work this way, so i have delay(x, 10) delay(y,20) and x is printed after 10 ticks, and y after 20 ticks but i dont have any idea how to do it, i mostly wanted to use it for animations, for now i have simple animation for 2 images which use 2 static ints and a boolean, 0 for first, 1 for second, but ive been thinking about some universal method

Comment: I suggest you look up [*lambda functions*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) and [`std::thread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread). What you want with your "delay" function can be implemented with a simple lambda and a [detached](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/detach) thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you simply need to declare two-additional functions so your static variables are different. You also need `if (i>=5)` instead of `if (i>5)`. For example you could do:

```
#include <iostream>

void func(){
    static int x=0;
    std::cout << " " << x++;
}

void func1(){
    static int x=0;
    std::cout << " " << x++;
}

void func2(){
    static int x=0;
    std::cout << " " << x++;
}

int main(){

    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        func();
        if(i>=5)
            func1();
        if(i>8)
            func2();
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/voidfunc
 0 1 2 3 4 5 0 6 1 7 2 8 3 9 4 0
```

**Using Single Function With 3-static Variables**

Another option is:

```
#include <iostream>

void func(){
    static int x=0;
    static int y=0;
    static int z=0;

    if (x <= 5)
        std::cout << " " << x++;
    else if (x <= 9)
        std::cout << " " << y++ << " " << x++;
    else
        std::cout << " " << y++ << " " << z++;
}

int main(){

    for(int i=0; i<=10; i++)
        func();

    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/voidfunc2
 0 1 2 3 4 5 0 6 1 7 2 8 3 9 4 0
```

**A Recursive Implementation**

As long as we are on the topic, I had one more idea. Why not use a recursive function? For example:

```
#include <iostream>

void func(){

    static int x=0;
    static int y=0;
    static int z=0;

    if (x < 6) {
        std::cout << " " << x++;
        func();
    }
    else if (x < 10) {
        std::cout << " " << y++ << " " << x++;
        func();
    }
    else
        std::cout << " " << y++ << " " << z++;
}

int main(){

    func();

    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/voidfunc3
 0 1 2 3 4 5 0 6 1 7 2 8 3 9 4 0
```

Just one more to add to the mix. Hopefully in one of the methods you can find what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks. but i came with this idea aswell, but i think it doesnt look so good and was wondering if there's a way to do it even more universal, my code for function is much longer, so addying 100 lines of code for every call of function(i might have like 15 independent calls) for my program which is only 800 lines long will probably destroy the whole overlook of code, but if there's no tool or trick for doing something like 'double static'(i know it's wrong) then thanks for this information aswell, at least i will not have something like i could do it better in my brain :)

Comment: @Lidbey - I came up with a single function way but using 3 variables. See if that is closer to what you thought. It's really just a matter of how you want to accomplish creating the sequence. (there are probably many ways)

Comment: It's fine, thank you for letting me know there is no syntax for my problem, the best solution i came up so far is calling an array: static int x[10] and calling func(int i), which works only on x[i], i think that's it for now, thanks for help!

Comment: @Lidbey - I had one more thought for a recursive implementation. I added that as well. No looping involved.